# How to check if change tracking is enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to determine if Change Tracking is already enabled on my database before I run the `ALTER DATABASE` command to enable it.  I am trying to prevent errors with these scripts if run multiple times.

I checked in `sys.databases` and `sys.dm_tran_commit_table` but was unable to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.change_tracking_databases 
WHERE database_id=DB_ID('MyDatabase')
```

Comment: So I was unfamiliar with Change Tracking and found this question searching about Change Data Capture (CDC). For others who happen to be here, the equivalent question/answer for CDC is [found here](http://zarez.net/?p=2821) `SELECT s.name AS Schema_Name, tb.name AS Table_Name
, tb.object_id, tb.type, tb.type_desc, tb.is_tracked_by_cdc
FROM sys.tables tb
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = tb.schema_id
WHERE tb.is_tracked_by_cdc = 1`

Comment: To check the current database, you can use `SELECT * 
FROM sys.change_tracking_databases 
WHERE database_id=DB_ID()` (no parameter)(

Comment: to help others, if you need to enable / disable this configuration you can use: 
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabaseName
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON